# Colors on my newly installed Ubuntu are pale and dim

Tags: drivers, graphics, screen, brightness, colors

Recently I build a new PC configuration and installed a 16.04 LTC on a new HHD. Everything is ok, except the colors that I have now, all of them are very pale and dim. First I kinda accepted that, I thought it was my just new Graphic card, which is Intel® Kabylake GT2.

But then I booted up from my old HHD, the old ubuntu 16.04 that I was using previously, and **the colors there are just fine.**

On the same PC, two versions of Ubuntu, different results.

I checked the drivers in use on both, they are the same (Intel ones).

So, what can be the cause of such difference?

Probably it can be caused by the fact that I was running Nvidia graphic card, and the drivers for it somehow changed display config. And if there is such a config, can I just copy it to the new system?

I tinkered gnome-color-manager, switched some profiles. No results, the changes there are very subtle, while the difference in colors between two system is huge.

Thanks for any pointers in direction on how to solve the problem.

Comment: If you have Nvida, run `nvidia-settings`

Comment: Where the colors fine when you had the open-source drivers?